# How to get the absolute path for a local maven artifact using groupId,ArtifactId,Version and packaging?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have the following string to search for the absolute path on my local repository ($HOME/.m2/repository):

e.g.: `com.group.example:myartifact:3.1:jar`

What I'd expect as output:
`$HOME/.m2/repository/com/group/example/myartifact/3.1/myartifact-3.1.jar`

Is there any way to achieve this lookup using **Apache Maven** and this information?

NOTE: The input can be separated as well, this way would be just convenient.

Comment: Question: Why do you need those path?

Comment: I have a remote repository and a certain team uses that info to get the artifact for their own local repository. After that, they want to run a plugin goal (independently of the project pom) for that downloaded artifact. The thing is, my example hides the complexity of the artifact, it is not a Jar, it is not Java, it is just the basic concepts of maven I looking for some way without to use external tools. The other possibility I have if no options comes up, is copy it for a local path that I have sure where is then provide that path through parameter for their command line.

Comment: If they have project pom they can simply make the maven build and everything needed will be downloaded ? Why do they need to make it independent from the build ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be two ways to achieve this.

---

## Method 1: Programmatically - by using maven's library

```java
import org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.ArtifactRepositoryLayout;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.DefaultRepositoryLayout;

Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact(groupId, artifactId, version, 
    null, extension, classifier, new DefaultArtifactHandler(extension));
ArtifactRepositoryLayout layout = new DefaultRepositoryLayout();
String artifactPath = layout.pathOf(artifact);
```

with dependency:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-artifact -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

In general, the above code uses maven's built-in code to get the artifact's relative path to the root of the local repository.

**LIMITATIONS:** This won't work with pseudo versions like `RELEASE` or `LATEST`

---

## Method 2: Use a dummy project and `dependency:list` goal

This method is more heavy-weighted and not programmatical, but works for all scenarios.

First, create a disposable pom.xml, like:

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- artifact information here -->
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then, running the following command under the parent directory of the above pom.xml:

```sh
mvn -B dependency:list -DoutputAbsoluteArtifactFilename=true -DexcludeTransitive=true | \
    grep -FA1 'The following files have been resolved:' | \
    tail -n 1 | \
    cut -d ':' -f6
```

And you'll get:

```
/home/vivimice/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.0-alpha5/slf4j-api-2.0.0-alpha5.jar
```